# How can I create React Native Navigation route?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, navigation

I am setting up a new route, and want to support about making new routes. What can I do?

My AppNavigator.js - Routes are in here

```
import { createStackNavigator, createAppContainer } from "react-navigation";
import Login from "../client/components/auth/Login";
import Register from "../client/components/auth/Register";

const AppNavigator = createStackNavigator({
  Login: { screen: Login },
  Register: { screen: Register }
});

const App = createAppContainer(AppNavigator);

export default App;
```

In App.js, I just imported AppNavigator

Register.js - I am trying to route to Login

```
import React from "react";
import {
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  TextInput,
  Button,
  TouchableOpacity
} from "react-native";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";

export default class Register extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate("Login")}>
          Have account? Login
        </Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a new stack with `createStackNavigator`. As far as I understand you want to redirect to another route after Log in. For that, you have to add them `createSwitchNavigator`. Then after successful login, you will redirect your route for example settings and for successful login you save the token in `Asyncstorage`. So, every time you load the app if you are successfully logged in you will be redirected to Setting page automatically otherwise the registration page will be loaded.

Here the code for App.js

**App.js**

```
import { createStackNavigator, createAppContainer,createSwitchNavigator } from "react-navigation";
import Login from "../client/components/auth/Login";
import Register from "../client/components/auth/Register";
import Setting from "../client/components/auth/Setting";
class AuthLoadingScreen extends React.PureComponent {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this._bootstrapAsync();

    }
  async _getStoredDataFromAsync(key) {
        return await AsyncStorage.getItem(key);
    }
 _bootstrapAsync = async () => {
        const userToken = await this._getStoredDataFromAsync("userToken");
        this.props.navigation.navigate(userToken ? 'App' : 'Some');
    };
 render() {
        return (

            <View style={{flex:1}}>
                <ActivityIndicator />


            </View>

        );
    }


}
const AppNavigator = createStackNavigator({
  Login: { screen: Login },
  Register: { screen: Register }
});
const SomeNavigator = createStackNavigator({
  Setting: { screen: Setting},

});
const Navigation = createSwitchNavigator(
    {
        AuthLoading: AuthLoadingScreen,
        App: AppNavigator ,
        Some: SomeNavigator ,



    },
 {
        initialRouteName: 'AuthLoading',
});
const App = createAppContainer(Navigation );

export default App;
```

Comment: Thanks, I will use it. But also one question, I want to redirect already registered users to login with "Have account? Login" button. How can I do that?

Comment: How about first load the Login page with "Don't have an account? Register"?
I think that is an easier and good way.

Answer (score 0):

you can use react-native router flux for navigation

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-router-flux